# Android: Custom video recording app and its quality

Tags: android-camera

I followed the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) to create a basic video recorder using the button ("Capture" & "Stop")

Generally it works well but I noticed that if we tap too rapidly on the button to toggle between "Capture to Stop" or from "Stop to Capture", the app stop responding and crashes.

May I know the reason(s) why and how can we solve this issue?

My guess is that it takes time for the app to start the processes of Capture/Stop respectively, and by rapidly tapping the button, the respective processes are force to stop?

Also, I notice the quality of my video recorder is not as good as the default Camera App that comes with Android. (The custom video recorder seems to capture videos of darker and dimmer quality)

Can this issue be solve by adjusting the Camera parameters? 
(For e.g. adjust the exposure compensation?)

Comment: I managed to solve the "button" issue by using boolean flags.

However I still need help on the "quality" issue.

Comment: TO determine the cause of the crash you need to look at the stack trace in logcat or attach a debugger.  How does the video quality in Grafika's custom recording compare (https://github.com/google/grafika)?  I found that setting the recording hint helped the frame rate; didn't really notice a change in quality.  What device are you using?

Comment: Thanks fadden. I'm using an Samsung S3.
One more issue. My video appears to be elongated in the y-direction (Everything appears to "grow taller"). This occurs when I use the dimensions of getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo() in 1920 X 1080 resolution. If I were to lower the resolution, the problem does not surface.
Does it has to do with the aspect ratio? And how to go about setting it?

Comment: The camera output is probably being scaled to match the view size.  You can compensate by adjusting the view dimensions.  See Grafika's AspectFrameLayout class for an example.